# Loop a public image directory that doesn't have an HTML file

Tags: javascript, iframe, directory, user-agent, noaa

I'm trying to dynamically get the images from the NOAA / National Weather Service here

https://radar.weather.gov/ridge/RadarImg/N0R/MTX

using JavaScript and it's proving to be tricky. Even though the names of the image files are standard/predictable, part of the naming convention includes the time at which the image was captured, and those times vary, so it makes more sense to loop through the directory instead of just making a lot of guesses. I know that scanning directories is generally not allowed because of the obvious security issues, so I tried opening it in an iframe, but there is no "index.html" file per se--all the html appears to be automatically generated by the browser, so there is no DOM to work with.

So has anyone dealt with something like this before? I'm stumped.

Comment: Do you mean some other directory? Because https://radar.weather.gov/ridge/RadarImg/N0R/MTX/ does list all the images it contains.

Comment: Nope, that's the one. If you notice the URL - there's no HTML file at the endpoint, you're just seeing those files in HTML generated by your browser (or at least that's what I'm seeing), so there's no DOM to run any script on.

Comment: That's not true. Your browser doesn't magically makes up HTML listings.
If you make an HTTP request to that URL, you get HTML back from the server, so you can absolutely iterate the DOM.

Comment: Yeah, I stand corrected on that - it's sending HTML and the browser is applying the styles. But, when I load it into an iframe and try to access it in code, it's empty:`<iframe id="noaaN1P" src="https://radar.weather.gov/ridge/RadarImg/N1P/MTX/" width="800pc" height="800px"></iframe>
<script>
    var iframe = document.getElementById('noaaN1P');
    var iframeDocument = iframe.contentDocument || iframe.contentWindow.document;
    console.log(iframeDocument );
</script>`

Comment: That's because you cannot access a cross origin iframe like that for security reasons. See below for a node.js solution.

Answer (score 0):

The server at that URL actually responds with the HTML you see in your browser.
Here is an example to parse the images from this directory in node.js:

```
const DOM = require('dom-parser')
const axios = require('axios')

axios.get('https://radar.weather.gov/ridge/RadarImg/N0R/MTX/').then((res) => {
  const dom = new DOM().parseFromString(res.data)
  const imageUrls = dom.getElementsByTagName('a')
    .map(link => link.getAttribute('href'))
    .filter(url => url && url.match('gif$'))
  console.log(imageUrls)
})
```